# Py3 - how to import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, import, airflow

I have the following folder structure for airflow setup. I want to unittests for dags, however I am unable to understand how to run the unittests due to the imports are done in pre-existing implementation of taski

```
.
+-- dags
|   +-- task1
|         +-- dag.py
|         +-- helper1.py
|         +-- helper2.py
|   +-- task2
|         +-- *.py
+-- tests
    +-- task1
          +-- test_*.py
```

Following are the import structures:

```
#dag.py 

from task1 import helper
```

```
#helper.py

from task1 import helper2
```

```
#test_validation.py

import unittest
from airflow.models import DagBag

class TestDag1(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.dagbag = DagBag(dag_folder="dags/")
```

I run the tests by invoking something like `python3 -m unittest discover -s tests`, this throws up error for imports, since it's looking at the dags/ folder as the **main** module, however with the current setup running on airflow, im unsure how to change the imports so everything stays in tact.

My question is, what I am doing wrong? the imports in dags implementation, or not tweaking unittest setup to import accordingly. how do i resolve this issue?

Python 3.8
Airflow 1.10.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly add the paths to the required files during runtime. For example, if `foo.py` needs to import something from `/some/path/some_file.py`:

```
# foo.py

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/some/path/')
from some_file import some_function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from task1 import helper2.py
```

It should be:

```
from task1 import helper2
```

Comment: sorry i made a typo in the question, will correct it.